# Combining Maya and QT with python

Tags: python, qt, maya

I recently learned python for scripting for Maya and other applications. As someone who sees big potential within scripting I use my self-written script pretty often to speed things up. But there is kinda missing the easy-to-use aspect. I always have to copy them from Sublime(Text Editor) into Maya. Thats when I asked my technical director how to implement a window for my scripts. He suggested QT for it, but even though I already created some simple window, I cannot get it to work in Maya with python.

I did not find any very useful tutorial for that :/

Is there maybe a full tutorial for that? Or can somebody help me?
Importing your windows as a module, attaching functions to buttons and so on.
I think it would be interesting for many people who wants to learn python for some applications.
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer myself after looking even more.

Here is a youtube link for a video from the "Maya Learning Channel" who shows it pretty well.
He is neither using PyQt nor PySide. Did not even know it works without these.
Good luck other people! ^^

Comment: Probably the best maya QT resources will be found at http://tech-artists.org/

You also need to pay attention to the version info on the tutorial, maya 2017+ are quite different from earlier versions.   You can also do fairly complex gui in Maya without QT using https://github.com/theodox/mGui

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. However QT Designer is at least easier to use than pure code, at least for me.